# How to add the 'DefaultCollection', when cloning a repo in yaml

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines, devops

I have this YAML snippet, to clone a second repo in my pipeline.

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: clone-scripts
      type: git
      name: 'DevOpsProject/pipeline-scripts'
      ref: 'refs/heads/main'
```

however, when executed, it shows this error

```
git remote add origin https://dev.visualstudio.com/DevOpsProject/_git/pipeline-scripts
git config gc.auto 0
git config --get-all http.https://dev.visualstudio.com/DevOpsProject/_git/pipeline-scripts.extraheader
git config --get-all http.proxy
git config http.version HTTP/1.1
git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier pipeline-scripts does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
fatal: repository 'https://dev.visualstudio.com/DevOpsProject/_git/pipeline-scripts/' not found
```

what I have seen, is that it is not taking into account the 'DefaultCollection' when executing

`git remote add origin https://dev.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/DevOpsProject/_git/pipeline-scripts  (OK)`

But how do you execute that, it's wrong

`git remote add origin https://dev.visualstudio.com/DevOpsProject/_git/pipeline-scripts`

Any ideas? in the Azure documentation, I have read but i can't find any information about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just to check those permisions in repo config

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: clone-scripts
      type: git
      name: 'DefaultCollection/DevOpsProject/pipeline-scripts'
      ref: 'refs/heads/main'
```

Comment: I tried to, but is not recognized 

TF200016: The following project does not exist: DefaultCollection. Verify that the name of the project is correct and that the project exists on the specified Azure DevOps Server.

Comment: Navigate to your Azure Devops repo and get the right URL. https://dev.azure.com/XXX/YYY/_git/yourRepo